# Display percentage inside the horizontal progress bar in android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I tried to implement the Horizontal Progress Bar in Android. It displays the percentage inside the progress bar and the position of that percentage is in the center of the filled area of the progress bar. I found various progress bars on GitHub and other sites. But, no one displays the percentage inside the progress bar and center of the filled area.
Please recommend me a progress bar that fulfills my requirements.

[image: The Progress Bar]

Comment: Check Example using Github repo. https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar

Comment: @Chirag Savsani, See the image carefully. I want something like that.

Comment: Yah that is for reference only. You can customize it. I created the same progress bar like yours using that GitHub repo.

Comment: Suggest what customization you do.

Comment: @MehulDhimmar, no one going to spoon-feed for your question.